# Set similarity join using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two text files each line is in the form of (id, sequence of numbers).
I have a threshold value as well.

File 1 looks like below where, in the first line, 0 is the id and rest is 
a sequence of numbers.

```
0 1 4 5 6
1 2 3 6
2 4 5 6
```

Similarly I have file 2 with following contents.

```
0 1 4 6
1 2 5 6
2 3 5
```

I have to find those lines which have similarity value greater or equal to a threshold. Similarity value can be calculated as the intersection of two lines divided by the union of two lines. For example line id- 0 of file1 has seq 1,4,5,6 and line id-0 of file2 has seq 1,4,6. They have intersection size = 3 and union size = 4. Therefore their similarity will be 3/4 = 0.75 which is greater than the threshold.

I have written python code to do this task and trying to convert it to Scala.

```
    with open("file1.txt") as f1:
        content1 = f1.readlines()
    content1 = [x.strip() for x in content1]

    with open("file2.txt") as f2:
        content2 = f2.readlines()
    content2 = [x.strip() for x in content2]

    threshold = 0.5
    final_index_list_with_similarity = []

    for i in range(len(content1)):
        for j in range(len(content2)):
            index_content1 = content1[i][0]
            index_content2 = content2[j][0]
            s = set(content1[i][1:])
            t = set(content2[j][1:])
            intersect = s & t
            intersect_size = len(intersect) - 1
            union_size = len(s) + len(t) - intersect_size - 2 #substracting two because I am getting two extra space.
            similarity = intersect_size/union_size
            if similarity >= threshold:
                final_index_list_with_similarity.append((index_content1, index_content2, similarity))
    print(final_index_list_with_similarity)
```

Output : `[('0', '0', 0.75), ('1', '1', 0.5), ('2', '0', 0.5), ('2', '1', 0.5)]`

What I have tried till now in scala is something looks like this.

```
val inputFile1 = args(0)
val inputFile2 = args(1)
val threshold = args(2).toDouble
val ouputFolder = args(3)

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SetSimJoin").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val lines1 = sc.textFile(inputFile1).flatMap(line => line.split("\n"))
val lines2 = sc.textFile(inputFile2).flatMap(line => line.split("\n"))

val elements1 = lines1.map { x => x.drop(x.split(" ")(0).length.toInt + 1) }.flatMap { x => x.split(" ") }.map { x => (x, 1) }.reduceByKey(_+_)
val elements2 = lines2.map { x => x.drop(x.split(" ")(0).length.toInt + 1) }.flatMap { x => x.split(" ") }.map { x => (x, 1) }.reduceByKey(_+_)
```

This gives me the frequency of every number in the entire file.

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both files can be joined as RDD, and then formula applied: "intersection size/union size":

```
val lines1 = sparkContext.textFile("inputFile1")
val lines2 = sparkContext.textFile("inputFile2")

val rdd1 = lines1.map(_.split(" ")).map(v => (v(0), v.tail))
val rdd2 = lines2.map(_.split(" ")).map(v => (v(0), v.tail))

val result = rdd1.join(rdd2).map(r => (
  r._1,
  r._2._1.intersect(r._2._2).size * 1.0 /
    r._2._1.union(r._2._2).distinct.size
)
)

result.foreach(println)
```

Output is:

```
(1,0.5)
(0,0.75)
(2,0.25)
```

Comment: thanks I got your solution. I did one change in that, I wanted something as cross join so in place of join I did cartesian and it worked fine for small data sets. But actually I have like half a million lines of data in a single file so in this I think join is not efficient enough to run it. So I have to look for something efficient.

Comment: In answer inner join is used, with cross join performance will be much worse.